What is the difference between CW and UW?
Community Wiki answers goes to CW but not to Ubuntu Wiki UW
What is the difference between these two websites?
I'm a bit confused on how Wiki works.

Also: What is the difference between the *.ubuntu.com wikis? on the main site
